# React-Native: Navigation between sign in and home screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create an app with login screen and a home screen with tabbed navigation.
But i cannot make it to navigate from sign in screen to home screen.
I am having error

`NAVIGATE with payload {"name":"HOME"} was not handled by any navigator`

Here's my App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import TabNavigation from './Screens/TabNavigation'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import SignInScreen from './Screens/SignInScreen'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function SplashScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Loading...</Text> 
    </View>
  );
}

const App = ({navigation}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null)

  const CheckUser = async()=> {
    let token
    try{
      token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('UserToken')
      setUserToken(token)
      setIsLoading(false)
    }catch{
      //failure code
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    CheckUser()
  },[])

  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {isLoading?
          <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />:
          (userToken==null?
            <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />:
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigation} />
          )
        }
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};
export default App;
```

Here's my SignIn.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const SignIn = ({navigation}) => {
    const _handleSignIn = async () =>{
        try{
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('UserToken', '123')
            navigation.navigate('Home')
        }catch{
            //failure here
        }
    }
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{_handleSignIn()}}>
                <Text>SignIn</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        backgroundColor: "red",
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    }
})
export default SignIn;
```

The TabNavigation component contains my Home screen navigation which works perfectly when  SignIn component is not used

EDIT: Here's code for TabNavigation

```
import React from 'react'
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import Screen1 from "./Screen1";
import Screen2 from "./Screen2";
import Screen3 from "./Screen3";

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()

const TabNavigation = () => {
    return(
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Screen1">
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
export default TabNavigation;
```

Comment: Can you share the code for TabNavigation as well ?

Comment: `userToken` is still null because you only get that value in the beginning. you need a way to update it or just get rid of `(userToken==null?` logic all together

Comment: This is not a problem of setting the userToken. it is about navigation between screens in the same stack

Comment: Agree with @MattAft the problem is your Home screen is not in the stack, so you cant navigate to it. Better use something like context to update userToken which will automatically redirect to home screen

Comment: @parvdesai `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigation} />` based on your code this screen only exists in your stack when `userToken` exists but it is always null so this is never in your stack and you can never navigate to it

Comment: @MattAft i am setting the userToken in sign in screen

Comment: @parvdesai yes but in `App` you're only fetching that value once...on app open so even though you set it on sign in, it's still null in `App` which means `Home` is never added to stack until you restart app and it gets new value. instead try storing it in a central place for both components to access like redux or context

Answer (score 0):

I think this part of your code is causing error:-

```
{isLoading?
      <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />:
      (userToken==null?
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />:
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigation} />
      )
    }
```

Try like:-

```
{isLoading===true && <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen}/>}
{isLoading===false && userToken===null? 
( <Stack.Screen name="SignIn"  component={SignInScreen} />):
(<Stack.Screen name="Home" component=  {TabNavigation} />)}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hi, so basically i have when a user logs in or registers for the first time i store their token until they log out which then i remove the token. Currently if a user object exists i render a tab navigator and if not i render a stack navigator. Is it possible that if a user object exists i render a screen then when button is pressed i render the tab navigator?